# Factory Apps for HTC First

Tags: system-apps

I recently received a HTC First that I'd like to use, and without rooting the phone I'd like to simply disable all the unnecessary apps that come with the phone. I don't really know where  to find these kinds of resources, but I am looking to use it for testing in App Development as well so I'd prefer more detailed rather than a wimpy general user sort of list if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, **`Uninstalling`** of pre-installed apps are not possible on **`unrooted`** phones.

But you can **`Disable`** some of the pre-installed apps.

Go to **`Settings->Apps-><your app name>`** and check whether you have **`Disable`** option.

**EDIT:**

If you can't find the **`Disable`** option, that means that you shouldn't disable it.

**Example:**

You **can Disable Alarm App**. 
But you **can't Disable Android System App**.

[image: You can **<code>Disable</code> Alarm App**]
[image: Can't **<code>Disable</code> Android System App**]

Comment: Sure, I'm capable of that, however I have quite a few apps that have ambiguous names such as: com.android.smspush or com.android.wallpaper.holospiral and com.google.android.voicesearch

Comment: And although I can try by trial and error, I'd like to know where the documentation is for them so I can fairly simply know what's vital and what's not at a glance.

Comment: @Kainui Edited. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Kainui I'm afraid there is no such "documentation". For some devices, you find lists for "apps safe to remove" in forums like XDA. As a thumb-rule: `com.android.*` is mostly core, and should not be touched. HTC's own stuff usually starts with `com.htc.*`. But as even those apps are woven deep into the system with Sense, some of them must also be kept. If you really want it "clean", you'll have to use a minimalist custom ROM.

Comment: More and more google apps are moving to com.google.android as the push them to the Play Store these days, then can be disabled generally (i.e. Google Keyboard, Google Drive etc) but not things like Google Play Services. There's no hard fast way, other than Google searching what you don't know and consulting XDA on your particular device/carrier/model.